# jQuery live mouseenter delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

I want to delay 2 seconds before the anonymous function is called on the mouseenter event. Here is the code that is working perfectly but I want to delay the initial animation or hover by 2 seconds and can't seem to figure it out.

```
$('div#response div.results').live({

    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('.zoomer').stop('true').css({
            'z-index': '999'
        }).animate({
            "overflow": 'visible',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            'width': '274px'
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            queue: false
        });
        $(this).find('img').stop('true').animate({
            "height": "180px",
            "width": "270px"
        }, {
            duration: 1,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        });
    },

    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('.zoomer').stop('true').animate({
            "overflow": 'visible',
            backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
            'width': '164px'
        }, {
            duration: 10,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        });
        $(this).find('img').stop('true').animate({
            "height": "108px",
            "width": "162px"
        }, {
            duration: 1,
            easing: 'easeOutCirc',
            queue: false
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us the relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
mouseenter:
       function()
       {
            setTimeout(function(){  
                 //your code
             }, 2000);
        }
```

Comment: this should work :P maybe with the emendation of declaring a `var $this = $(this)` and using that in your current code where you have `$(this)`

Comment: Still Didn't work.. It works if I just put alert('test'); but not if I paste in the rest of my code

Comment: put before that setTimeout `var $this = $(this)` and replace everything `$(this)` to `$this`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.zoomer')...delay(2000).animate(...
```

Use the delay function?